# Trigger callback when map navigation completes React-Native

Tags: google-maps, react-native

Currently, I have a use case of returning to my application from google maps when the user reaches to the destination.

Having read some articles, it is known that performing this functionality in IOS may not be possible. However, [on reading this article](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme), i tried using

```
comgooglemapsurl://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=Tokyo+Tower,+Tokyo,+Japan&sll=35.6586,139.7454&sspn=0.2,0.1&nav=1
&x-source=nameOfMyApp
&x-success=urlOfMyApp://?resume=true
```

which does not trigger the callback. Is there any other settings that is to  be made that I am missing?

Also, what would be the approach for the same in android?